# Simply or Alias running a command with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I have some long running processes that I run with nohup and redirect any output to a log. Since I usually like to monitor directly, at least at the beginning, I add a tail as well. This end up looking something like this.

```
nohup myprocess.sh >> 20180611.log 2>&1 & tail -f 20180611.log
```

Not that this is super complicated, but I was hoping I could find a way to create an alias for it. I could probably do this with a wrapper script, but I didn't want to clutter the directory with essentially two scripts per process (hence me thinking of an alias). Thanks!

Comment: An alias is a word that is replaced with something else (a longer fragment of a command) when it is the first word of the command. It cannot take arguments. You can, however, write a shell function (in your `.bashrc`) to do the processing you want (and pass the process name and the log file as arguments).

Comment: Not really the topic here but you might be interested a terminal multiplexer like `screen` of you have long-running stuff to manage and want to log off before it has finished.  `nohup` is the poor man's solution to this from the 70s.  For many use cases there's better stuff around by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alias is a word that is replaced with something else (a longer fragment of a command) when it is the first word of the command. It cannot take arguments.

You can, however, write a shell function (in your `.bashrc`) to do the processing you want (and pass the process name and the log file as arguments).

It could look like this (in `.bashrc`):

```
function no-hup() {
    nohup "$1" >> "$2" 2>&1 & tail -f "$2"
}
export -f 'no-hup'
```

You run it like this:

```
no-hup myprocess.sh 20180611.log
```

Comment: That's handy, but if I am still passing the arguments, it doesn't really provide a simplification like I was looking for.  My hope is something just like "process1" which would alias/kick off the full command in my question.

Comment: If you always want to run `myprocess.sh` and put its output in `20180611.log` then you can simply hardcode these values in the function's body. Or you can write it as an alias: `alias foo="nohup myprocess.sh >> 20180611.log 2>&1 & tail -f 20180611.log"`

Comment: I'd also recommend adding `disown` so the process can keep running uninterrupted if the shell exits: `no-hup() { nohup command &>> file & disown; tail -f file; }`

Comment: Tangentially, I like `less +GF file` over `tail -f`: you can Ctrl+C to stop tailing but stay in less, and use less commands to browse/search in the file. To start tailing again, use "G" to go to end of file and "F" to start following.

Comment: @axiac The process would be hard-coded, but the log file would be set to the current date. I suppose I might be able to put that together in that function.

Comment: I got it figured out by storing date in a variable, then using that to call nohup and push to the background, then call tail. I think it is close enough that I'm just going to accept this answer since it got me on the right track. Thanks!